# How to open a new file in the current directory with gvim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, home-directory

If I'm working on a file located on e.g. `~\myprojects\testproject\hello.txt` and then want to open a new file in the same directory e.g. `todo.txt` (located on `~\myprojects\testproject\todo.txt`), how can I do that efficiently with gvim on Windows?

Today I have to type this command, maybe using tab-completion for the paths:

```
:e ~\myprojects\testproject\todo.txt
```

Is there any shorter command e.g:

```
:e .\todo.txt
```

in gvim on Windows?

If I use `.\todo.txt`, that file will be located on `C:\Windows\system32`, that's not even my home directory. Is there any setting to specify my home directory as default instead? or any other diectory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work, provided your current dir is where the file is:

```
:e todo.txt
```

For the second question I don't know a good answer. You can of course do

```
:cd ~
```

every time you start up, or you could edit your vimrc to do that. It's a hack and not a good solution.

There's also 'autochdir' if you want to cd to the file every time. I found it here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

In your vimrc you would put in this line:

```
set autochdir
```

Edit2: add answer to second question

Comment: No, that file is also place in `C:\Windows\system32` and not in `~\myprojects\testproject\todo.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I will come back with a proper answer soon.

Comment: How about now? Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
map <Leader>e :e <C-R>=expand("%:p:h") . "/" <CR>
```

This opens the command line, enters the 'e'  command and pre-populates the file argument with the path to the file in the currently active buffer. The  key is mapped to the backslash key by default.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, if you are editing a file in that directory at the moment, `set autochdir` in vim.rc should be enough.

If you are however in the vim file explorer (`netrw`)

```
:e .
%filename
```

you will have to precede the creation of a new file with `%`.

For more information: `:help netrw-intro-browse`.